# How to improve visibility of Android Nougat quick setting tiles?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, user-interface, 7.1-nougat, usability

Android Nougat introduces Quick Setting tiles that are available from pulling down the status bar on the top of the screen.

Unfortunately, on many devices, the tiles are light gray icons on a white background, which makes them very hard to see.

Furthermore, when they are enabled, the icons switch to cyan on white.  This makes differentiating between the *on* and *off* states challenging in good lighting, and nearly impossible in bright light.

For non-rooted devices, how can the quick setting tiles be changed to use a dark background, or at least, implement a higher contrast?

Comment: Lately I found a theme customizing app called substratum which is primarily for rooted devices, but works on some Nougat ROMs even without root. Have you tried it? If it worked for you, you can unveil wide plethora of themes and UIs for your phone.

Comment: @bikalpa Thank you.  I've been looking at some info on it thanks to your comment.  I see it definitely themes apps, but does it theme the quick setting tiles?

Comment: I think it does(I have not tried it though, I'm saying on the basis of screenshots seen on web). It kinda changes your system in the root level so don't forget to take a backup though.

Comment: @bikalpa That's why I haven't tried it yet.  How can you make a root backup without root?

Comment: Through custom recovery. You don't need to be rooted to install a custom recovery. All you need to do is unlock the bootloader.

Comment: @bikalpa Thank you!  Do you know if that voids warranty for most devices?

Comment: Unfortunately unlocking bootloader voids warranty in most of the devices. But if you own a Oneplus phone, they do support warranties even after unlocking the bootloader or rooting the phone.